# Codeigniter Active Record with nested "SELECT WHERE"

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I was wondering if there was any way in Active Record to create a query with nested `WHERE`  cases like:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE FirstName = 'John' AND (LastName = 'Smith' OR LastName = 'Jones');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use `where()` function

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('Users ');
$this->db->where("FirstName = 'John'");
$this->db->where(" (LastName = 'Smith' OR LastName = 'Jones') ");
$result=$this->db->get();
```

[**Active Record**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. I wasn't aware you could enter straight SQL like that in the where function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the WHERE clause in order to do this.

```
$this->db->where("FirstName = 'John' AND (LastName = 'Smith' OR LastName = 'Jones')");
```